# Lumen Api, Android Post Response - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: lumen-5.2

My project has three part e.g. Lumen-5.8(API), Angular-8(web), Android(Mobile). The POST method is working in Angular but not working in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are developing API. So you need to care about request and response type.

Ex. In Android, If you are expecting string response from API but your API send you integer then you will get 500 error.

Comment: yes, there is problem in request param issue. Now it is solving after debugging line by line. thanks.